# HTML Regex help

Tags: html, regex, vim

I have to do a large replacement on a wp_posts.sql and I want to remove all the `<a href>` and `</a>` tags. I am trying to do this with VIM but I cant figure out the regular expression for it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hopefully the community will be able to help shortly.  Do you have specific examples of what you've tried so far?

Comment: note that regex is not an encouraged tool for HTML. A parser should be used instead.  E.g. a simple regex can not discern tags that are actually commented out or something like that. Neither can a complex one ever cover all problem cases. That being said, you may just be lucky enough not to run into problems when you use a regex for this simple case

Comment: Without more restrictions regex cannot be used. For example, Tomalak's answer will fail on something like `<a href="javascript:f(a>b)">`.

Comment: @ZyX: He's asking for a one-off regex for use in a text editor, not one for production use in some library. That's a small but significant difference.

Comment: @Tomalak: It does not mean that more restrictions are not needed. He can't use regex even in text editor if it is going to produce wrong results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove entire `<a>` tags (with content):

```
:%s!<a[^>]\+>[\s\S]\{-}</a>!!g
```

To remove *just* the tags (keep content):

```
:%s!<a[^>]\+>\|</a>!!g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with python, the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module performs magic on html.  It might be worth your while to look into it.